# Metal functions failing to compile with Xcode 8

Tags: ios, xcode, metal

Since moving to Xcode 8 and iOS10, my metal based app fails to run at all. On launch I get the error: "Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED"

This appears two to three times in the console before crashing due to a `MTLComputePipelineState` not being successfully created and throwing an error when calling the `MTLDevice` function `makeComputePipelineState(function:)`. The only changes I have made to the project is to update to Swift 3.0, but the console seems to imply a compiler error, which due to the crash I'm assuming is down to some metal code not compiling properly.

Any help would be appreciated, this is ageing me prematurely.

UPDATE:

I've located the line causing the trouble in the `.metal` file:

```
int gi1 = permMod12[ii+i1+perm[jj+j1+perm[kk+k1]]];
```

permMod12 is a static constant array declared as:

```
static constant int permMod12 [512] = {7,4,5,7...}
```

perm is similarly static and constant:

```
static constant int perm [512] = {151,160...}
```

The variables `ii`, `i1`, `jj`, `j1`, `kk` and `k1` are all integers calculated in the same kernel.

The kernel is quite large so I'll post a [link](https://github.com/AndyHeardApps/AHNoise/blob/master/AHNoise/Generators.metal) to the GitHub location. It's the functions called `simplex3D` and `simplex4D` that are causing the issue. These are very similar so only focus on one of them, they are carbon copies but 4D has another stretch of variables running (`ll`, `l1`, `l` etc).

The issue certainly seems to be with looking up these arrays with calculated variables as when I change the variables to simple literals there is no error.

The kernel needs to be executed in order to get the error to occur.

Any help with this new info would be great.

Comment: This is almost certainly a compiler bug. Please check the device logs in Xcode for crashes in MTLCompilerService and attach the log to a radar containing as much other information as you can provide.

Comment: After checking, there are no crashes with MTLCompilerService contained in them.

Comment: Also worth noting, it runs fine when I attempt to run a kernel with no other function calls. The error pops up when I attempt to call another function from within the kernel. Not at my PC right now but I'll upload an example when I am

Comment: @warrenm I've added more information if it helps at all. This one has completely thrown me.

Comment: I am getting this error with a simple graphics shader when loading a `.metallib` file.  Is it better to compile from source at runtime as I cannot see what is causing the issue (new to MSL)?

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the same error: "Compiler failed with XPC_ERROR_CONNECTION_INTERRUPTED". The issue was resolved. It stemmed from attempted use of 'threadgroup bool' type variables. Refactoring the code to use 'threadgroup short' variables in place of the boolean resolved the error. (Could not find in the Metal Version 2 specification if bool type is or is not a valid threadgroup type.)

Comment: I also ran into this problem with a threadgroup array of type uint8_t, changing that to an array of uchar2 and reading and writing 2 bytes at a time fixed the problem. The compiler seems to require at least 16 bit width elements in a threadgroup item.

Comment: I think MoDJ's statement "The compiler seems to require at least 16 bit width elements in a threadgroup item" is exactly what it's all about. Would be nice if the compiler error would be more specific though.

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered this situation, and it seems that there is no unique solution to solve this problem. In my case, the problem was occurred when a texture that uses a normalized coordinate sampler also uses `read()` function. When I switch `read()` function to `sample()` this weird error was removed. I hope your problem were solved already.